# How to select particular fields from an association in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following models

```elixir
schema "products" do
  field :quantity, :integer
  field :price,    :float
  field :discount, :float, default: 0.0

  belongs_to :order, Order
end

schema "orders" do
  field :received_at,   Ecto.Date
  field :shipment_cost, :float
  field :savings,       :float
  field :shop_name,     :string

  has_many :products, Product
end
```

What I want to do now is to fetch an order with a particular fields: `savings` and `shipment_cost`.

I need also associated product for that order, but once again, also with only specific fields: `quantity`, `price` and `discount`.

How to do that in the most efficient way?

```elixir
def for_amount(order_id) do
  products_query = from product in Product,
                     select: %{
                       order_id: product.order_id,
                       quantity: product.quantity,
                       price:    product.price,
                       discount: product.discount
                     }

  from order in Order,
    preload: [products: ^products_query],
    where:   order.id == ^order_id,
    select:  [order.savings, order.shipment_cost]
end
```

I also tried

```elixir
def for_amount(order_id) do
  from order in Order,
    join:    products in assoc(order, :products),
    where:   order.id == ^order_id,
    select:  %{
                savings:       order.savings,
                shipment_cost: order.shipment_cost,
                quantity:      products.quantity,
                price:         products.price,
                discount:      products.discount,
              }
end
```

but this enforces me to use `Repo.all` and returns a list of joins of course.

Comment: We don't have a way of doing exactly what you want yet, sorry. However, I would honestly just return the entire data, unless you have really heavy columns (containing binary information for example). It will make your code cleaner until we support something in Ecto.

Comment: To be clear, I am advocating your first example, but without the selects. :)

Comment: OK, thanks @JoséValim. Can I make `products_query` return `Product` record instead of map (but keeping the feature of limiting fields)?

Comment: No, not yet. We have discussions about supporting this in Ecto, but it is still early on. As I said, I wouldn't worry about it for now unless you really have to. :) By the time it becomes a problem, if it ever does, we will have a syntax for it. :)

Comment: Any news here @JoséValim? I have a column with binary data that I would like to exclude in preloads/joins but couldn't figure out a nice way yet.

Comment: Am looking for a way to filter out certain association records using composable queries, any solutions?